# Parsing columns with BeautifulSoup and saving as JSON

Tags: python, html, json, beautifulsoup

I would like to Parse the Afk., Aantal and Zetels columns on the website: http://www.nlverkiezingen.com/TK2012.html that I can eventually save as a JSON file.

Before saving it as a json file, I need to parse the elements.

I had

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

jaren = [str("2010"), str("2012")]

for Jaargetal in jaren:
    r = urllib.urlopen("http://www.nlverkiezingen.com/TK" + Jaargetal +".html").read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")
    tables = soup.find_all("table")

    for table in tables:
        header = soup.find_all("h1")[0].getText()
        print header

        trs = table.find_all("tr")[0].getText()
        print '\n'
        for tr in table.find_all("tr"): 
              print "|".join([x.get_text().replace('\n','') for x in tr.find_all('td')])
```

Ive tryed

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

jaren = [str("2010"), str("2012")]

for Jaargetal in jaren:
    r = urllib.urlopen("http://www.nlverkiezingen.com/TK" + Jaargetal +".html").read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")
    tables = soup.find_all("table")

    for table in tables:
        header = soup.find_all("h1")[0].getText()
        print header

        for tr in  table.find_all("tr"):
            firstTd = tr.find("td")
            if firstTd and firstTd.has_attr("class") and "l" in firstTd['class']:
                tds = tr.find_all("td")

                for tr in table.find_all("tr"): 
                    print "|".join([x.get_text().replace('\n','') for x in tr.find_all('td')])
                    break
```

What am I doing wrong or what do I have to do, am I on the right track?

Comment: Could you point what is wrong exactly with the existing code? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe In the first code it prints all of the rows:  Partij|Afk.|Aantal|%|+/-|Zetels I would like to have the code only print the rows: Afk. Aantal and Zetels.

Answer (score 0):

One option to extract the desired columns only would be to check indexes of the columns. Define the column indexes you are interested in:

```
DESIRED_COLUMNS = {1, 2, 5}  # it is a set
```

And then use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) with `find_all()`:

```
"|".join([x.get_text().replace('\n', '') 
          for index, x in enumerate(tr.find_all('td')) 
          if index in DESIRED_COLUMNS])
```

Comment: Thanks @Alecxe is there also an option that I can define something to only get the first 3 rows from afk, Aantal and Zetels for example?

Comment: @Danisk you can always slice, for example: `tr.find_all('td')[:3]`

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have another quick question; this works now, the only thing is that I am scraping from 2012 and 2010. 2010 has more les rows than 2012, so it scrapes also content that I don't want. Is there an option to say. "tr.find_all td [:20] from website 2010 and tr.find_all('tr')[:19] from 2012

Comment: @Danisk sorry for the previous comment. I meant, you should not be trying to limit the amount of rows you extract - this is the dynamic part.